# Shape Rotation Issue - Java2d

Tags: java, vector, awt, java-2d

I am developing one simple game in which i have encountered one small but important issue.
I have implemented absolute rotation in my logic.

When i start rotating an object when the object does not have any rotation , it works fine and i can rotate as in any direction without any problem as shown in the following link.

[Initial Rotation Video](http://www.screenr.com/6oaH)

Now the problem arise when the object does have some rotation , and why i try to rotate in one of the direction , instead of being rotated in desire direction the rotation always starts from initial rotation as shown in the following link.

[Rotation issue when shape has some rotation](http://www.screenr.com/QoaH)

I think the video shows everything , still if you have any questions please ask me.

I think the problem is , there should be a relative rotation in the direction of mouse pointer from whatever circle is selected .

Now about My Logic,

in mouse press event i just checked

## Mouse Press

Whether the shape is selected on the canvas , if yes 
if one of the four circles contains mouse point if yes
then initiateRotation

## Mouse Drag

Using Vector Maths
I update the motion according to mouse points ,

calculate rotation angle according to the following method

```
Math.atan2(rotationVector.getY(), rotationVector.getX());
```

and apply rotation on this shape.

Rotation Vector i get from this class

[Vector Rotation](http://pastebin.com/TuxEJdb7)

I called above class startMotion in mouse press and updateMotion in mouse drag event.

**What am i missing or doing anything wrong ?**

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't normalize vectAB before returning it? Also did you check that bounds.getCenterX/Y returns the the correct coordinates? Or maybe the error is in the method that applies the rotation to the shape.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see some code to be able to help you out. It looks like you reset the rotation, whenever you initiateRotation, and then the object quickly rotates in place, according to your mouse position when you drag.

Comment: Well, complete mouse click and drag functions, and methods for rotating things. Also any of your own classes, that are relevant to your problem. Like the shapes, if you're not using standard Java shapes. It's a good idea to tell us what you're using for your project, otherwise we haven't a chance. Remember, short code can be added to your question, while full classes and methods, could have their own snipt.org (remember to change language from abap to Java)